# Checking if a value exists in randomly generated array

Tags: python, arrays, list

An array is randomly generated by a fixed code and we have to work based on that code. I need to check if a specific value is existing in the array or not.

I have tried these two solutions but none of these works:

```
if a[5][0] in a
if a[5][0] != ""
```

I have provided an example of the array

```
[['Stack 5', 'Suit C', 9, 0],
  ['Stack 4', 'Suit B', 6, 0],
  ['Stack 6', 'Suit B', 8, 0],
  ['Stack 3', 'Suit C', 3, 0],
  ['Stack 1', 'Suit C', 10, 0],
  ['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 4, 0]]
```

Basically I need to check if 'Stack X' is present in the array and then to conduct the operations. Sometimes, the randomly generated array might miss any certain stack, for instance,

```
[['Stack 5', 'Suit C', 9, 0],
 ['Stack 4', 'Suit B', 6, 0],
 ['Stack 6', 'Suit B', 8, 0],
 ['Stack 3', 'Suit C', 3, 0],
 ['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 4, 0]]
```

Stack 1 is not generated in this case and I need to check if it has been generated or not. It is basically an array within an array.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your help guys but I solved the issue using a for loop. Here is the code I used.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][0] == 'Stack 1':
```

Comment: Do you merely want to check _if_ there exists a matching sub-list -- or does "to conduct the operations" mean that you also need to do something based on the other values of the matching sub-list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
def a_contains(num):
    for item in a:
        if 'Stack {}'.format(num) in item:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I think slicing may be faster than iterating, although I'm not entirely sure

Comment: If you like a more declarative style, you might prefer `any(item[0] == 'Stack {}'.format(num) for item in a)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in syntax for that. Probably the best shot is to use `any` and list comprehension

```
In [8]: data = [['Stack 5', 'Suit C', 9, 0], 
   ...:  ['Stack 4', 'Suit B', 6, 0], 
   ...:  ['Stack 6', 'Suit B', 8, 0], 
   ...:  ['Stack 3', 'Suit C', 3, 0], 
   ...:  ['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 4, 0]]                                                                       

In [9]: any(l[0] == 'Stack 1' for l in data)                                                                
Out[9]: False

In [10]: any(l[0] == 'Stack 3' for l in data)                                                               
Out[10]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to toss them in a `numpy` array you could slice the first column and run your check that way:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.array([['Stack 5', 'Suit C', 9, 0],
  ['Stack 4', 'Suit B', 6, 0],
  ['Stack 6', 'Suit B', 8, 0],
  ['Stack 3', 'Suit C', 3, 0],
  ['Stack 1', 'Suit C', 10, 0],
  ['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 4, 0]])

if 'Stack 6' in data[:, 0]: # index all rows, and only first column
    print('yes')
if 'Stack 18' in data[:, 0]:
    print('found')
else:
    print('nope')
```

Outputs:

```
yes
nope
```

Additionally a `print(data[:, 0])` yields:

```
['Stack 5' 'Stack 4' 'Stack 6' 'Stack 3' 'Stack 1' 'Stack 2']
```

I *think* that using slicing in a `numpy` array is faster than iterating through the list, but I have not timed it personally

Comment: `data[:]` is just `data`. `'Stack 5' in data[:][0]` returns true only because it is in the first list

Comment: Thanks. Will check it and let you know.

Comment: @Marat Ah yes you are correct. I'm thinking of `numpy` slicing. I'll try to edit it so it works

Comment: @Marat thanks for pointing that out. I just converted my answer to `numpy` slicing in case the OP would prefer that

Comment: Cannot import any library other than turtle, random and math; we are bound to work on these only.

Comment: I have resolved the issue through; using a for loop.

Comment: @JoeJulen Awesome! For future reference you should include module restrictions in your post. Also, be sure to click the check mark by the post that solved your problem to give the author props and tell future viewers of the post where to look! When you get 15 rep you can also up-vote helpful questions and answers. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

For loop, each time checks in each sub array if the requested values exists.

Check the code below.

```
data = [['Stack 5', 'Suit C', 9, 0],
  ['Stack 4', 'Suit B', 6, 0],
  ['Stack 6', 'Suit B', 8, 0],
  ['Stack 3', 'Suit C', 3, 0],
  ['Stack 1', 'Suit C', 10, 0],
  ['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 4, 0]]

req = "Stack 8"
ans = ""
for l in data:
  if req in l:
    ans = "yes"
    break
  else:
    ans = "no"

print(ans)
```

Comment: I had basically the same answer. OP doesn't want `numpy` in his code though apparently.

Comment: OP  doesn't say anything in the description of the question about numpy.

Comment: Hey said it in a comment on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yourList = [['Stack 5', 'Suit C', 9, 0],['Stack 4', 'Suit B', 6, 0], ['Stack 6', 'Suit B', 8, 0], ['Stack 3', 'Suit C', 3, 0], ['Stack 1', 'Suit C', 10, 0], ['Stack 2', 'Suit B', 4, 0]]
filteredList = list(filter(lambda x: 'Stack 1' in x, yourList))
if (len(filteredList) > 0):
    #your code
```